# Import .CPP files from a working iOS project and rename to .mm issue

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, objective-c++

I have copied a .CPP and its .h file from a working project to a new one.

I renamed the ending from .CPP to .mm but it still gives me errors.

In the .h file, near the class definition
`class MeterTable`,  it says it expect the `;`

In the .mm file, there are all kinds of errors.

I thought by changing the ending of the implementation file .mm it would clean all those errors. And yes, the original .CPP file compiled under the old project.

Comment: Could you post the line(s) of the header file that cause the error? Could you also post a literal quote of the error message? Could you be more specific about the "all kinds of errors" in the implementation .mm file? Which version of Xcode are you using?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you're including that `.h` file into some other `.m` file. You cannot just include C++ header into a C or Objective-C source file. You need to make sure that your C++ interface is C compatible (no classes, only free functions without overloading). Or you would have to change all your `.m` files in the project into `.mm`.

Answer (score 0):

The only solution is to have an inline header file.

Change your **.h** file to **.hpp** and combine your **.cpp** file with your **.h** file.

As example; your **.h** file:

```
// class.h

class {
public:
    void someclass(int a);
};
```

And your **.cpp** file:

```
// class.cpp

#include "class.h"

void someclass(int a) {
    return;
}
```

Merge into **.hpp** like this:

```
// class.hpp

class {
public:
    void someclass(int a) {
        return;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Objective-C and C++ can play nicely together, but there are a couple of caveats.  First, any `.m` file that references C++ code (i.e., via a header) must be defined to be an Objective-C++ source, *not* Objective-C.  This can be done on a case-by-case basis by going to the File Inspector for the `.m` file and changing the file type from `Objective-C Source` to `Objective-C++` source.  Second, use the same method to define the `.h` and `.cpp` (or `.mm`, the actual extension does not really matter, it's the defined types) as `C++ Header` and `Objective-C++` source, respectively.

As long as you use this compartmentalization of file types, you should be able to mix Objective-C and C++ freely -- I commonly use this paradigm to consume C++ in my iOS code.