# Objective C adding C++

Tags: c++, objective-c, objective-c++

I have been given some C++ classes to incorporate into my Objective C project.  I've never done this before, so I have to ask:

1. Is there something special I need to do or can I just rename the .cpp to .mm?
2. What about importing (or including) the .h file?  Anything special I need to do there?

Just baby steps here.  Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried renaming files and including the .h and have it fail?

Comment: Yes.  In my interface, I get the following two errors:  Missing context for method declaration and Expected method body.  I think that is because of what is in the C++ header file, but I don't know much about C++.

Comment: I think you have to rename almost every file in your project to `.mm` for this to work, otherwise the compiler just tries to compile using Objective-C instead of Objective-C++.

Comment: Every file that includes the C++ header will have to be switched over to Objective-C++. Remember how the C (and Objective-C and C++) build model works.

Comment: @bames53 - Answer the question, so I can give you some points.  Thank you very much.  Your comment made it very clear what I needed to do.  All the C++ classes could keep their .cpp extension.  Only the Objective-C classes that import the C++ header files need the .mm extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember how the C build model works; It is the Objective-C files including C++ headers that must be switched over to Objective-C++.

Answer (score 1):

See my answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12920598/import-cpp-files-from-a-working-ios-project-and-rename-to-mm-issue) question.  Basically, the `.mm` convention is a nicety, not a necessity.  If you use the File Inspector to set up the file types of the `.h\.m\.cpp` files correctly, you can get Objective-C to play nicely with C++ files without difficulty.