# iOS: calling C++ singleton using Objective-C

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode8

I have C++ singleton implementation like this:

```
#include "DoingSomething.hpp"
class DoingSomething
{
    static DoingSomething *shareInstance;

    public:

    int doSomething()
    {
        /*

         */

        return someValue;
    }

    static DoingSomething *instance()
    {
        if (!shareInstance)
            shareInstance = new DoingSomething;
        return shareInstance;
    }
};
```

But I want to access the singleton and the public functions inside of the singleton on my viewController using Objective-C. Any of you knows how can this be done?

I'll really appreciate your help.

Comment: adding a `.mm` file ending to your source code turns the file into an objective-c++ source file. It understands both objective-c and c++ in the same source file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calling C++ from Objective-C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19229574/calling-c-from-objective-c)

Comment: @Sneak, to the post are pointing is unclear how to access to C++ singleton. Per one of the post " self.mmclass = [[CplusplusMMClass alloc]init];  // bad practice; but showing code"

Comment: @user2924482 Since you are calling a singleton I don't see why you would need to store the singleton as a property, therefore you dont need to call self.mmclass =....  Did you see the example project linked in the comment section?